# VAR for Non Stationary series using R

Tags: r, time-series, multivariate-analysis, vector-autoregression, stationarity

Are there any suggested approaches for using non-stationary series in a VAR model? As per [otexts.org](https://www.otexts.org/fpp/9/2):

> If the series are non-stationary we take differences to make them stationary and then we fit a VAR model (known as a “VAR in differences”).

Are there any other approaches for creating a forecasting model non-stationary series in a multivariate series?

Any leads on this would be helpful. I'm looking for implementing this model in `R`.

Comment: Either a VAR in first differences or a vector error correction model (VECM) depending on whether your series are cointegrated. See e.g. [this](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/148994/var-or-vecm-for-a-mix-of-stationary-and-nonstationary-variables/149263#149263) which is a more general case, but easy to simplify. See also [this](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/191851/var-forecasting-methodology/195477#195477) for a general cookbook approach to VAR modelling.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the information provided. The only way to identify stationarity of var is to check the stationarity of constituent variables?

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Comment: @LalPrasadR you DON'T need to first difference data to forecast with VAR (sorry this is one of my pet pervs)!!!  Read my post here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/191851/var-forecasting-methodology/195477#195477

Answer (score 1):

To use VAR model for non-stationary series, you have to test the cointegration 
If there is cointegration you use the model VECM
Otherwise a VAR on the first differences of the variables

Comment: Thank you for the information provide. So if we need to predict from the VECM mode, we need to go for Rolling forecasts?