# Interpretation Dickey-Fuller Test

Tags: r, time-series, unit-root, augmented-dickey-fuller

```
ur.df(data, type = "trend", lags = 20, selectlags = "AIC")
```

This is my output :

**Value of test-statistic is: -3.1535 3.6559 5.1012**

`Critical values for test statistics: 
      1pct  5pct 10pct
tau3 -3.96 -3.41 -3.12
phi2  6.09  4.68  4.03
phi3  8.27  6.25  5.34`

From what i read i would say that at 5pct : **tau3** is accepted (there is a unity root) ; **phi3** is rejected since the test-statistic 5.1012 < 6.25 critique value and **phi2** is rejected

**where**

- tau3 refers to the null hypothesis that there is a unit root.
- phi3 refers to the null hypothesis that there is a unit root AND no-trend (without trend)
- phi2 refers to the null hypothesis that there is a unit root without trend and without drift

am i missing something ? i already read

[Interpreting R's ur.df (Dickey-Fuller unit root test) results](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/24072/interpreting-rs-ur-df-dickey-fuller-unit-root-test-results)

this post but i'm still not sure if i am right

Answer (score 1):

The correct interpretation of the above example is :

we accept tau3 (null hypothesis : there's a unit root) at 5pct because
 -3.1535 is NOT < -3.41

we accept phi3 (null hypothesis : there's a unit root AND no-trend) because 
5.1012 is not > 6.25

we accept phi2 (null hypothesis : there is a unit root without trend and without drift) because 3.6559 is not > 4.68

Answer (score 0):

This would also be true for a 1 pct level, right?

we accept tau3 (null hypothesis : there's a unit root) because -3.1535 is NOT < -3.96

we accept phi3 (null hypothesis : there's a unit root AND no-trend) because 5.1012 is not > 6.09

we accept phi2 (null hypothesis : there is a unit root without trend and without drift) because 3.6559 is not > 8.27