# Difference between Trend and Level stationarity

Tags: r, time-series, stationarity, trend, kpss-test

In R KPSS test, what is meaning of level and trend stationarity?

As far as I have read, trend stationarity means that once you remove the trend, the process becomes stationary. Is this the correct definition of trend stationarity? I do not know the meaning of level stationarity. I found a similar question, but no one in the answer defines the level stationarity. Here is the link to that post: [KPSS: Difference between level stationary and trend stationary](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/411077/kpss-difference-between-level-stationary-and-trend-stationary)

Comment: Hi @Mohit. "Level stationary" means that the time series is stationary in the natural units of the variable. Thus, the series does not require a transformation (e.g. first-differencing or de-trending) to make stationary. It already is. "Trend stationary" means that the series requires de-trending to make stationary, just as stated above.

Comment: @EB3112: Can you please make that into n answer, that is, in the answer box? So that thw Q does not linger on as unresolved!