# ARIMA Model Residuals correlation in small sample?

Tags: time-series, correlation, estimation, arima

I'm working with simulated data, trying to estimate the best ARIMA model for a time series consisting of 100 observations.
This is the original data. 
[image]

First of all, I performed a combination of ADF and KPSS (following what was posted [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/129842/best-practice-for-adf-kpss-unit-root-testing-sequence?rq=1) and [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/251557/interpretation-of-ur-df-output-in-r-dickey-fuller-test-package-urca)) tests which suggested that the original series was not stationary and had a unit root.
[image]

After differentiating once, I ran the tests again and no indication of unit root was shown. In addition to that, I couldn't reject the null for the KPSS test.
[image]

After that, I used auto.arima (focusing on BIC criteria for model selection). I also created a pool of models and ranked them according to BIC (which, as expected, did not match the auto.arima suggestion). 
This is a data.frame that I created with each model's specification and it's corresponding BIC value. 
[image]

After that, I started testing the residuals of each model: 
Ran several normality tests (JB, SW, K-S) as well as plots for visual identification of 'normality'. So far, no issues here for any model.

The problem appears when I run the Ljung-Box test to test for correlation of the residuals.
For every model that I tested, the residuals appear to be correlated. For one particular model, I even tested for the presence of ARCH effect (using Q and LM tests) and there were signs of such effect.

So this is the first question: is it possible that this effect is due to the small sample, disregardless of the model chosen? Or is it possible that I need to differentiate again in order to eliminate this issue? 
Among the models in the table, there are some that require differentiation a second time. Did that, tested for autocorrelation (again, using Ljung-Box test) in the residuals and couldn't reject the null. 
All this is shown in the next image: 
[image]

Am I failing to identify the presence of unit root after differentiation for the first time? Is it auto.arima as well as my function that created a pool of models failing to identify the need for a second differentiation? 
Or is there any explanation given the size of the data for this issue with the autocorrelation of residuals?

If necessary, data can be found **[here](http://www.mediafire.com/file/w84wat0jlw3x7y5/SerieB.txt/file)**.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: i am having problems downloading your data .please email it to me dave@autobox.com

Comment: Sent it. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

Ok I did model your series.

1. Unit root test, i did a adf test and chose the trend equation since your serie seems to have one, i didnt reject h0 so unit root, I diff the serie and do an other adf test that tells me the serie is now stationnary.

[image]

[image]

I then used minimization criterion method and it chooses a MA(3) but on diagnostic test for residual, I had autocorrelations so in this case you rise order of p and/or q until you don't have anymore.

It led me to an ARMA(1,5) on the diff serie (so an ARIMA(1,1,5) on original serie)

Here the estimates with all coefficients significant at 10%:

[image]

And here the diagnostic test for residuals, LB test until the 24th order to confirm no autocorrelation at 5%:

[image]

[image]

I have a fairly normal distribution that can allow you to interpret your confidence interval.

For your information, I used SAS 9.4 as you can see and PROC ARIMA.

The methodology is always the same as Box-Jenkins: Statio the serie, find the optimal order based on criterion of your choice (AIC/BIC for explanatory and MSE/others for predictive) and diagnostic test on residuals, normality hypothesis isnt always mandatory if you don't interpret confidence intervals

Answer (score -1):

I took your 100 values into AUTOBOX a piece of software that I helped to develop and it suggested a model of (2,0,0) [image]. The residual plot looked clean [image] with a satisfactory acf of the residuals here [image] siggesting sufficiency.

The tests that your are using are not always as bad as you present them to be here BUT on the other hand I don't find any of them to be of any substantive value when you have data that has pulses, level shifts, seasonal pulses , local time trends , changes in parameters over tine , changes in error variance over time or any other Gaussian Violation .

Your data is adequately modeled with an ar(2) process WITHOUT any differencing... anything else is unwarranted and superfluous. Can you disclose what the parameters you specified for your simulation ?

[image]

So this is the first question: is it possible that this effect is due to the small sample, disregardless of the model chosen?

I have no idea ...

Or is it possible that I need to differentiate again in order to eliminate this issue?

I don't think u need an other order of differencing

Comment: This post does not answer any of the questions specifically asked: "Am I failing to identify the presence of unit root after differentiation for the first time? Is it auto.arima as well as my function that created a pool of models failing to identify the need for a second differentiation? Or is there any explanation given the size of the data for this issue with the autocorrelation of residuals?"