# R: interpreting ur.df ADF test results

Tags: r, time-series, econometrics, unit-root

I'm running ADF test on my data to test for unit root and stationarity, trend, and to find the optimal number of lags using `urca` package.

my code is as follows:

```
> resADFaic <- lapply(InvestmentTS,function(x){ summary(ur.df(x,type="trend", selectlags = "AIC")) })
```

> resADFaic

(this is to `lapply` the `ur.df` test on all variables in my data)

this test yields, for an example of one of the variables:

```
############################################### 
# Augmented Dickey-Fuller Test Unit Root Test # 
############################################### 

Test regression trend 


Call:
lm(formula = z.diff ~ z.lag.1 + 1 + tt + z.diff.lag)

Residuals:
      Min        1Q    Median        3Q       Max 
-0.242639 -0.009059  0.002046  0.016602  0.065003 

Coefficients:
              Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)   
(Intercept)  0.1428625  0.0627106   2.278  0.02436 * 
z.lag.1     -0.0951398  0.0432642  -2.199  0.02966 * 
tt          -0.0003743  0.0001349  -2.776  0.00633 **
z.diff.lag   0.0133259  0.0905665   0.147  0.88325   
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 0.03429 on 129 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.05708,   Adjusted R-squared:  0.03515 
F-statistic: 2.603 on 3 and 129 DF,  p-value: 0.05479


Value of test-statistic is: -2.199 2.9918 3.858 

Critical values for test statistics: 
      1pct  5pct 10pct
tau3 -3.99 -3.43 -3.13
phi2  6.22  4.75  4.07
phi3  8.43  6.49  5.47
```

I am completely lost on how to interpret these results. Firstly, how do I test for the presence of a unit root (stationarity)? Secondly, how can I determine if there is trend? Finally, how do I interpret the lags? what is the tt coefficient?

I have already read: [Interpretting R's ur.df (Dickey-Fuller unit root test) results](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/24072/interpreting-rs-ur-df-dickey-fuller-unit-root-test-results) and am still very much lost. Any input would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: I have figured out the first 2 questions about unit-root and trend. I am still very much confused about the lags.

Comment: The lags are just a device to account for short-run serial correlation in the series so as to make sure inference on the unit root property is valud. They are rarely of interest in their own right.

Comment: How would you infer the unit root given the lags above then?

Comment: You need to compare the test statistic -2.199 to the critical values for tau3 - that, actually, seems to be question 1 about unit roots which you said you figured out, unless I am mistaken?

Comment: I thought that tau3 was to indicate stationarity, having nothing to do with lags? That interpretation is based on the answer linked in my question.

Comment: "How would you infer the unit root given the lags above then?" relates to if there is a unit root according to the test, as far as I understand. To repeat, there is nothing to infer about the unit root property of the series from the coefficients on `z.diff.lag`. They just serve to control for remaining serial correlation.