# ADF tests: phi2 and phi3 explodes when differencing

Tags: time-series, stationarity, unit-root, augmented-dickey-fuller, differencing

ADF tests are used to inform on the order of integration of a time series. With the function `ur.df`, three different specifications can be used, called "trend", "drift" and "none". These are explained quite well [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/24072/interpreting-rs-ur-df-dickey-fuller-unit-root-test-results).

Now, how would you explain the following changes in the p-values of the coefficients when more and more differences are taken?

1. Original data with type = "trend"

```
   tau3     phi2     phi3
**-3.020791 6.173046 4.907725**
```

2. First differences of data with type = "trend"

```
   tau3     phi2     phi3
**-3.862442 5.086268 7.626563**
```

3. Second round of first differences with type = "trend"

```
   tau3     phi2     phi3
**-5.005805 8.376976 12.55419**
```

4. Third round of first differences with type = "trend"

```
   tau3     phi2     phi3
**-6.741858 15.19711 22.75069**
```

The pattern is very clear. When more rounds of first differences are used, the null of a unit root can be more strongly rejected. At the same time, the test statistics `phi2` and `phi3` explode. I am not perfectly sure why this is the case. How can the test statistic on `phi2` increase after differencing?

From the other thread: "Rejecting this null implies that one, two, OR all three of these terms was NOT zero."

Do the statistics for `phi2` and `phi3` only increase due to the stationarity becoming even stronger? Or is this an artifact of the test interpreting the differencing as some kind of trend?